# SonarQube github action not able to get projectKey

Tags: github, gradle, sonarqube, github-actions

Currently trying to add SonarQube to my project with github actions. The issue is that it can't get the projectKey and that it somehow tries to get a spring bean without having spring boot in my project. The code is as following:

Build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.7.0'
    id 'java'
    id 'org.owasp.dependencycheck' version '6.3.2'
    id 'com.google.cloud.tools.jib' version '3.2.1'
    id 'org.sonarqube' version '3.4.0.2513'
}

....

sonarqube {
    properties {
        property("sonar.projectKey", "NotificationApi")
        property("sonar.projectBaseDir", "src")
    }
}
```

Build.yaml:

```
on:
  # Trigger analysis when pushing in master or pull requests, and when creating
  # a pull request.
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]

name: NotificationApi Build
jobs:
  sonarqube:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: SonarQube Scan
        uses: sonarsource/sonarqube-scan-action@master
        env:
          SONAR_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}
          SONAR_HOST_URL: ${{ secrets.SONAR_HOST_URL }}
```

With the following error:

```
WARN: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ClassRealm{javascript}-org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.EslintBridgeServerImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 4; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'AnalysisTempFolder' defined in org.sonar.scanner.analysis.AnalysisTempFolderProvider: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'provide' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'DefaultInputProject' defined in org.sonar.scanner.scan.InputProjectProvider: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'provide' parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ProjectReactor' defined in org.sonar.scanner.scan.MutableProjectReactorProvider: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.sonar.api.batch.bootstrap.ProjectReactor]: Factory method 'provide' threw exception; nested exception is You must define the following mandatory properties for 'Unknown': sonar.projectKey
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 29.603s
ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
ERROR: You must define the following mandatory properties for 'Unknown': sonar.projectKey
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarScanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
INFO: Final Memory: 22M/77M
```

What is wrong about this configuration and what needs to be changed to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [action README file](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube-scan-action#usage) as well as [this thread](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/monorepo-and-sonar-project-properties/52812), adding the `projectBaseDir` input to the **SonarQube Scan** step should make it work (informing the folder where the `sonar-project.properties` file is located):

```
      with:
        projectBaseDir: <project-folder>
```

That way the project-level `sonar-project.properties` files should be detected correctly.

In your case it would look like this:

```
      - name: SonarQube Scan
        uses: sonarsource/sonarqube-scan-action@master
        with:
          projectBaseDir: <project-folder>
        env:
          SONAR_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}
          SONAR_HOST_URL: ${{ secrets.SONAR_HOST_URL }}
```

---

In case you didn't create the project `sonar-project.properties` file yet:

> Project metadata, including the location to the sources to be
> analyzed, must be declared in the file `sonar-project.properties` in the base directory:

```
sonar.projectKey=<replace with the key generated when setting up the project on SonarQube>

# relative paths to source directories. More details and properties are described
# in https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/ 
sonar.sources=.
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works fine for many env's and many apps

```
name: Sonarqube Scan CI

on:
  # Trigger analysis when pushing in master or pull requests, and when creating a pull request. 
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
      types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  sonarqube:
    name: Execute SQ CI
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.config.os }}
    concurrency:
      group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.ref }}
      cancel-in-progress: true
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        config:
          - { os: [dev-ci-runner-cluster], account: "dev", env: "dev" }

        app: ["api", "frontend"]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          # Disabling shallow clone is recommended for improving relevancy of reporting
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: SonarQube Scan ${{ matrix.app }}
        uses: sonarsource/sonarqube-scan-action@master
        env:
          SONAR_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}
          SONAR_HOST_URL: ${{ secrets.SONAR_URL }}
        with:
          projectBaseDir: ${{ matrix.app }}
```